# Extended limit laws for step by step evaluation of limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Most textbooks of calculus / real analysis present a version of limit laws which help us to infer about limit of sum or product of functions provided the limits of individual functions are known to exist. Such rules also go by the name *algebra of limits*.

In this post and my answer to it I provide an extended version of these laws which are more helpful in step by step evaluation of a limit. Before I state those laws it is better to give some introductory remarks.

If $f$ is a real valued function defined in certain deleted neighborhood of point $a$ then the *limiting behavior* of $f(x) $ as $x\to a$ can be of one of the following types:

- $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) $ exists. Although it is redundant to state, to avoid confusion / ambiguity this means that the limit exists as a finite real number. We also say that $f(x) $ *converges* to a real number as $x\to a$. Example $\lim_{x\to 0}x$.
- $f(x) \to \infty $ as $x\to a$. We say that $f(x) $ *diverges* to $\infty $ as $x\to a$ and some prefer to write this in symbols as $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =\infty$. Example $\lim_{x\to 0} (1/x^2)$.
- $f(x) \to - \infty $ as $x\to a$. We say that $f(x) $ diverges to $-\infty $ as $x\to a $ and some prefer to write this in symbols as $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =-\infty$. Example $\lim_{x\to 0} (-1/x^2)$.
- $f(x) $ *oscillates finitely* as $x\to a$. More formally this means that $f$ is bounded in some deleted neighborhood of $a$ and there exist *at least two distinct* real numbers $A$ and $B$ and two sequences $\{a_n\}, \{b_n\} $ of numbers in the deleted neighborhood of $a$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=a=\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n) =A, \lim_{n\to\infty} f(b_n) =B$$ Example $\lim_{x\to 0}(1/x)-\lfloor 1/x\rfloor$.
- $f(x) $ *oscillates infinitely* as $x\to a$. This means that there is a sequence $\{a_n\} $ of numbers in deleted neighborhood of $a$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=a, \lim_{n\to \infty} |f(a_n) |=\infty$$ and *yet* neither $f(x) \to\infty $ nor $f(x) \to-\infty $ as $x\to a$. Example $\lim_{x\to 0}(1/x)\sin(1/x)$.

The above list is exhaustive and consists of mutually exclusive possibilities. Sometimes the second and third options are combined together and one says that $f(x) $ diverges as $x\to a$. Similarly the fourth and fifth options can be combined to say that $f(x) $ oscillates as $x\to a$.

Now we come to extended limit laws.

> **Theorem 1**: Let $f, g$ be functions defined in a certain deleted neighborhood of $a$ and let $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) $ exist and be equal to $L$. Then the limiting behavior of $f(x) \pm g(x) $ as $x\to a$ is of exactly the same type  as that of $g(x) $ and we can write $$\lim_{x\to a} \{f(x) \pm g(x) \}=\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \pm\lim_{x\to a} g(x) =L\pm\lim_{x\to a} g(x) $$ The case of divergence can be same or opposite (as regards to sign of $\infty$) depending on the sign $\pm$ which combines $f, g$.
>
> **Theorem 2**: Let $f, g$ be defined in a certain deleted neighborhood of $a$ and let $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =L\neq 0$. Then the limiting behavior of $f(x) g(x) $ as $x\to a$ is of exactly the same type as that of $g(x) $ and we can write $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) g(x) =\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \cdot \lim_{x\to a} g(x) =L\lim_{x\to a} g(x) $$ The case of divergence can be same or opposite according as $L>0$ or $L<0$. Also the case of convergence holds when $L=0$ but other cases can't be guaranteed when $L=0$.

Both these theorems can be used to evaluate the limit of a complicated expression in a step by step manner by handling one term or one factor at a time whose limit is known thereby reducing the expression to a simpler form at each step. Each step is justified on the basis of the term/factor whose limit is known irrespective of the behavior of other terms/factors.

Moreover the theorems indicate that each step is reversible and hence holds unconditionally. This is better than using the standard limit laws which basically say that the limit has to be applied simultaneously on each part of the expression on the condition that each part has a limit and parts occurring as denominator have non-zero limit.

> I will provide proof of one of the theorems as an answer (to be marked community wiki). I expect users to provide other point of views regarding these theorems and any improvements in my question and answer are also welcome.

**Note**: The above is a more formal and detailed version of the rules presented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/72031) and it is based on a [request in a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2968842/help-find-the-mistake-in-this-problem-of-finding-limit-using-lhopital?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment6131585_2968853) to another question.

Comment: I use the terms "exists finitely" for case $1$ (or "converges"), "exists infinite" for case $2$ and $3$ (or "diverges") and doesn't exist otherwise. Your definitions are more detailed!

Comment: @gimusi: yes "exist finitely" is common in my country.

Comment: Thanks for that contribution, I'll take a closer look to that!

Comment: I'm just stopping by briefly, so I haven't absorbed everything you've written, but for me at least, once one is at this level of detail, you may as well use the properties of $\liminf$ and $\limsup,$ which not only reproduces all these results, but gives more general versions of them. For example, if one of the assumptions is that a limit exists finitely, then the assumption is really $\limsup = \liminf < \infty,$ which can then be incorporated into the conclusion.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: you are right, but the concepts of limsup, liminf, are bit tricky to grasp. Also The post is already long (sorry :)) so I don't want to add them. Best would be that you add the equivalent formulation based on limsup /liminf as an answer if time permits.

Comment: I was searching for something I'd written and I came across something ELSE I'd written, and it occurred to me that this other thing I'd written might be of interest to you, at least if you wind up extending your formulations (or use another answer to extend your formulations) to limsup/liminf descriptions. (Presently, I'm not sufficiently interested or have time to do this myself.) See my answer to [Sufficient condition for equality of limsups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834649/sufficient-condition-for-equality-of-limsups/2834830#2834830).

Comment: Thanks @DaveL.Renfro. I will add a reference to your answer in my post after some time. Not everyone pays attention to fine details in comments.

Comment: @Andrew: It would be best if you can ask your problem as a question here. Nothing beats mathematics stack exchange when you want any help on solving a maths problem.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, I was thinking of the term reversible (I ask just to understand it deeper), when we have e.g.: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$, is the canceling of $x-2$ reversible since it doesn't equal $0$? I would be thankful if you would include every further and past mistakes of mine to help others because I'm quite creative when it comes to making mistakes. Also, can I interpret the $\text{additive manner}$ in which replacing a term by its limit is allowed, as a linear combination?

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya: cancelling is an algebraic manipulation which has nothing to do with calculus. You can and should apply such manipulation to simplify your expression. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1822706/72031) for more details.

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya : also don't generalize a term to a linear combination.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, I read the question/answer carefully and see the point. Actually, many of my former teachers mixed the terms $\text{not defined at a certain point}$ and $\text{discontinuous}$ which is not the synonym, for example $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. I really admire your work and hope my colleagues will look for already answered questions here because they rely on assistants and a few of us who speak English. If you have time, here is a link to a math site of my colleague, teacher and best friend: http://halapa.com/

Comment: The only problem is the language, but students from all around the world send him tasks and I started helping him recently with English and formatting. I mentioned him beacuse he always talks about Indian mathematicians and their approach to problems. If you have any advice on the literature, I'll be glad to send him an e-mail.

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya: I recommend only one book for those who read my answers (on calculus) and blog: *A Course of Pure Mathematics* by G H Hardy, 10th edition.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I have seen this post before also when you had shared it in one of the comments.My only Qn. here is:if $f\to \infty$ and $g$ oscillates finitely when $x\to a$, say, can we say something about $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)g(x)$? More specifically, will it converge on $\mathbb R$? If $g$ oscillates between say $p$ and $q$  it follows that if $p$ and $q$ have the same sign then $fg\to \infty $ or $-\infty$ but the problem comes when $p$ and $q$ have opposite signs. In this case, my claim is $fg$ will oscillate infinitely and that is based on intuition. Can you help with the proof? Thanks.

Comment: @Koro:in this case $fg$ oscillates infinitely.

Comment: @Koro: you can also see that $fg$ won't converge because if it did converge to $L $ then $g=fg/f$ converges to $L/\infty=0$ (I hope you can do this rigorously). In short all your claims are correct and do try to give a rigorous proof. If you face any issue you can ask as a separate question. This will also help future readers of this site.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ParamanandSingh :). Sure. I'll ask as a separate question in case any  issue arises.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a proof of theorem 2 and is presented more as an outline and the details can be easily filled by anyone familiar with proofs of usual limit laws.

The case of convergence is the one usually presented in common textbooks and for this case it can be written explicitly as

> Let $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L\neq 0$. The limit of $f(x) g(x) $ as $x\to a$ exists if and only the limit of $g(x) $ as $x\to a$ exists.

The "if" part is a direct application of usual product rule of limits. The "only if" part is also a consequence of the usual algebra of limits (mainly the quotient rule). Just write $h(x)=f(x) g(x)$ and then since $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =L\neq 0$ by quotient rule we have $$\lim_{x\to a} g(x) =\lim_{x\to a} \frac{h(x)} {f(x)} =\frac{1}{L}\lim_{x\to a} h(x) $$

If $L=0$ then the "if" part holds but not the "only if" and thus the process of splitting the limits is not reversible.

Next we deal with the case of divergence and here we assume $L>0$. We then show that $f(x) g(x) $ diverges to $\infty$ as $x\to a$ if and only if $g(x) $ does so. First we deal with "if" part and thus let $g(x) \to \infty $ as $x\to a$. And consider any arbitrary $M>0$. By existence of limit of $f$ there is a $\delta_1>0$ such that $f(x) >L/2$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta_1$ (this is done by choosing $\epsilon=L/2>0$ in definition of limit). Again since $g(x) \to\infty $ there is a $\delta_2>0$ such that $g(x) > 2M/L$ (note the $L\neq 0$) whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta_2$. If $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ then for $0<|x-a|<\delta$ we have $f(x) g(x) >(L/2)(2M/L)=M$ so that $f(x) g(x) \to\infty $ as $x\to a $. The case when $g(x) \to - \infty $ is similar. For $L<0$ the conclusion is same apart from a reversal of sign of infinity.

The "only if" part for divergence can be proved using the "if" part itself. Consider $G(x) =f(x) g(x), F(x) =1/f(x)$. Then by quotient rule $F(x) \to 1/L$ and $1/L$ has same sign as $L$. Thus by the proof in last paragraph $g(x) =F(x) G(x) $ diverges if $G(x) =f(x) g(x) $ diverges.

The case of oscillation presents no significant difficulty. Let's handle the case of  finite oscillation here. We show that $f(x) g(x) $ oscillates finitely as $x\to a$ if and only if $g(x) $ does so. We prove the "if" part and the "only if" part can be deduced from the "if" part as done in case of divergence. Since $f(x) \to L$ therefore $f$ is bounded in some deleted neighborhood of $a$. And since $g(x) $ oscillates finitely it is also bounded. The product $f(x) g(x) $ is thus bounded in some deleted neighborhood of $a$. There exist numbers $A, B, A\neq B$ and sequences $a_n, b_n$ such that $a_n\to a, b_n\to a$ and $g(a_n) \to A, g(b_n) \to B$. Since $f(x) \to L$ we have $f(a_n) \to L, f(b_n) \to L$ and by product rule for sequences we have $$f(a_n) g(a_n) \to LA, f(b_n) g(b_n)\to LB$$ Since $L\neq 0$ and $A\neq B$ we have $LA\neq LB$ and thus $f(x) g(x) $ also oscillates finitely as $x\to a$.

The crucial part to note here is that in each case the condition $L\neq 0$ makes the whole process reversible ie it changes "if" (one way implication) to "if and only if" (two way implication). This is important to validate the step by step application of the rule *unconditionally*.

A proof of theorem 1 is similar and one should try to understand why we don't need the requirement $L\neq 0$.