# Finding $\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{x^{(\sin x)^x}-(\sin x)^{x^{\sin x}}}{x^3}$

Tags: limits

## Problem

$$\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{x^{(\sin x)^x}-(\sin x)^{x^{\sin x}}}{x^3}.$$

## Attempt

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{(\sin x)^x}-(\sin x)^{x^{\sin x}}}{x^3}\\
=&\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\exp [(\sin x)^x\ln x]-\exp [{x^{\sin x}\ln(\sin x)]}}{x^3}
\\=&\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\exp [{x^{\sin x}\ln(\sin x)]}(\exp [(\sin x)^x\ln x-{x^{\sin x}\ln(\sin x)}]-1)}{x^3}
\\=&\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\exp [{x^{\sin x}\ln(\sin x)]} [(\sin x)^x\ln x-{x^{\sin x}\ln(\sin x)}]}{x^3}
\end{align*}
This will help?

Comment: A CAS claims that it is $1/6$, which indicates that l'Hospital should be used three times ...

Comment: Same question: [$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{x^{(\sin  x)^x}-(\sin  x)^{x^{\sin  x}}}{x^3}=\frac{1}{6}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195547/how-to-calculate-the-following-limit-in-a-clever-way)

Comment: @YuiToCheng Your post is helpless. No solution is there.

Comment: @YuiToCheng: I was about to move my answer to that question, but that question asks for no Taylor series.

Answer (score 7):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
&\log\left(\frac{x^{\sin(x)^x}}x\right)\\[3pt]
&=\log(x)\sin(x)^x-\log(x)\\[6pt]
&=\color{#C00}{\log(x)}\,\color{#090}{x^x}\color{#00F}{\left(\frac{\sin(x)}x\right)^x}-\log(x)\\
&=\color{#C00}{\log(x)}\color{#090}{\left(1+x\log(x)+\frac{x^2\log(x)^2}2+\varepsilon_{3,3}\right)}\color{#00F}{\left(1+\varepsilon_{3,0}\right)}-\log(x)\\
&=x\log(x)^2+\frac{x^2\log(x)^3}2+\varepsilon_{3,4}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
&\log\left(\frac{\sin(x)^{x^{\sin(x)}}}x\right)\\[3pt]
&=\log(\sin(x))\,x^{\sin(x)}-\log(x)\\[9pt]
&=\color{#C00}{\log(\sin(x))}\,\color{#090}{x^x}\color{#00F}{x^{\sin(x)-x}}-\log(x)\\[3pt]
&=\color{#C00}{\left(\log(x)-\frac{x^2}6+\varepsilon_{4,0}\right)}\color{#090}{\left(1+x\log(x)+\frac{x^2\log(x)^2}2+\varepsilon_{3,3}\right)}\color{#00F}{\left(1+\varepsilon_{3,1}\right)}-\log(x)\\
&=x\log(x)^2+\frac{x^2\log(x)^3}2-\frac{x^2}6+\varepsilon_{3,4}
\end{align}
$$
where $\varepsilon_{m,n}=O\!\left(x^m\log(x)^n\right)$.

If $u,v\to0$, then $e^u-e^v=(u-v)\left(1+\frac{u+v}2\right)+O\!\left(u^3\right)+O\!\left(v^3\right)$. Thus,
$$
\frac{x^{\sin(x)^x}}x-\frac{\sin(x)^{x^{\sin(x)}}}x=\frac{x^2}6+\varepsilon_{3,6}
$$
and therefore,
$$
\frac{x^{\sin(x)^x}-\sin(x)^{x^{\sin(x)}}}{x^3}=\frac16+\varepsilon_{1,6}
$$
That is,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^{\sin(x)^x}-\sin(x)^{x^{\sin(x)}}}{x^3}=\frac16}
$$

---

**In General**

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\left(x+O\!\left(x^3\right)\right)^{x+O\left(x^3\right)}
&=\color{#C00}{x^x}\color{#090}{x^{O\left(x^3\right)}}\color{#00F}{\left(1+O\!\left(x^2\right)\right)^{x+O\left(x^3\right)}}\\[3pt]
&=\color{#C00}{\left(1+x\log(x)+\tfrac12x^2\log(x)^2+\varepsilon_{3,3}\right)}\color{#090}{(1+\varepsilon_{3,1})}\color{#00F}{(1+\varepsilon_{3,0})}\\[3pt]
&=1+x\log(x)+\tfrac12x^2\log(x)^2+\varepsilon_{3,3}\tag1
\end{align}
$$
where $\varepsilon_{m,n}=O\!\left(x^m\log(x)^n\right)$.

Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(x+ax^3+o\!\left(x^3\right)\right)
&=\log(x)+\log\left(1+ax^2+o\!\left(x^2\right)\right)\\[3pt]
&=\log(x)+ax^2+o\!\left(x^2\right)\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
&\log\left(x+ax^3+o\!\left(x^3\right)\right)\left(x+O\!\left(x^3\right)\right)^{x+O\left(x^3\right)}-\log(x)\\[3pt]
&=x\log(x)^2+\tfrac12x^2\log(x)^3+ax^2+o\!\left(x^2\right)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
If $u,v\to0$, then $e^u-e^v=(u-v)\left(1+\frac{u+v}2\right)+O\!\left(u^3\right)+O\!\left(v^3\right)$.

Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac1x\left[\left(x+a_1x^3+o\!\left(x^3\right)\right)^{\left(x+O\left(x^3\right)\right)^{x+O\left(\lower{.5pt}{x^3}\right)}}
-\left(x+a_2x^3+o\!\left(x^3\right)\right)^{\left(x+O\left(x^3\right)\right)^{x+O\left(\lower{.5pt}{x^3}\right)}}\right]\\[6pt]
&=(a_1-a_2)x^2+o\!\left(x^2\right)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{x^3}\left[\left(x+a_1x^3+o\!\left(x^3\right)\right)^{\left(x+O\left(x^3\right)\right)^{x+O\left(\lower{.5pt}{x^3}\right)}}
-\left(x+a_2x^3+o\!\left(x^3\right)\right)^{\left(x+O\left(x^3\right)\right)^{x+O\left(\lower{.5pt}{x^3}\right)}}\right]\\[6pt]
&=a_1-a_2
\end{align}}\tag5
$$
and this verifies the other limits in the [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3195547) (which wanted an answer without Taylor series).

Comment: The $\varepsilon$ notation is an interesting choice

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: it was mainly to save horizontal space :)

Comment: Thanks！ Your solution is nice, but not complete, that's to say, you omit some process including expanding $x^x$ and so forth, which is not so obvious to us.

Comment: $x^x=e^{\color{#090}{x\log(x)}}=1+\color{#090}{x\log(x)}+\frac12\color{#090}{x^2\log(x)^2}+\overbrace{O\!\left(\color{#090}{x^3\log(x)^3}\right)}^{\varepsilon_{3,3}}$ I tried to make this clear by coloring $x^x$ and the expansion green in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment (I don't have the points so...)

We have :

$$\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{x^{(\sin x)^x}-(\sin x)^{x^{\sin x}}}{x^3}=\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{-x^{(\sin x)^x}+(Arcsin (x))^{(x)^{Arcsin (x)}}}{x^3}.$$

So we introduce the following function :
$$f(x)=x^{sin(x)^x}$$

We have to prove :

$$\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{-f(x)+f(Arcsin(x))}{x^3}$$

Or
$$\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{(-f(x)+f(Arcsin(x)))(Arcsin(x)-x)}{(Arcsin(x)-x)x^3}$$

But :

$$\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{(Arcsin(x)-x)}{x^3}=\frac{1}{6}$$

And

$$\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{(-f(x)+f(Arcsin(x)))}{(Arcsin(x)-x)}=1$$

For the last limit I use the three chord lemma and the fact that the function $f(x)$ is convex on $[0;\varepsilon]$ for $\varepsilon$ very small (near from 0).

Comment: Would you please explain how we have the first equation?

Answer (score 0):

### My Solution

Recall the following formulas
$$\sin x=x-\frac{1}{3!}x^3+\frac{1}{5!}x-\cdots\tag 1$$
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\cdots\tag 2$$
$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots \tag 3$$
which are the starting point we need to rely on.

From$(1)$,
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin x-x}{x}=\dfrac{x-\dfrac{1}{3!}x^3+o(x^4)-x}{x}=-\frac{1}{6}x^2+o(x^3).\tag{4}
\end{align}
From $(3)(4)$,
\begin{align}
\ln\sin x&=\ln\left(x\cdot \frac{\sin x}{x}\right)=\ln x+\ln\left(1+\frac{\sin x-x}{x}\right)\notag\\
&=\ln x+\frac{\sin x-x}{x}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\sin x-x}{x}\right)^2+o(x^4)\notag\\
&=\ln x-\frac{1}{6}x^2+o(x^3).\tag{5}
\end{align}
From $(5)$,
$$x\ln\sin x=x(\ln x-\frac{1}{6}x^2+o(x^3))=x\ln x-\frac{1}{6}x^3+o(x^3).\tag{6}$$
From $(2)(6)$,
\begin{align*}
(\sin x)^x&=\exp(x\ln\sin x)=1+x\ln\sin x+\frac{1}{2}(x\ln\sin x)^2+\frac{1}{6}(x\ln\sin x)^3+o(x^3\ln^3 x)\notag\\
&=1+x\ln x+\frac{1}{2}x^2\ln^2 x+\frac{1}{6}x^3\ln^3 x+o(x^3\ln^3 x).\tag{7}
\end{align*}
From $(7)$, we obtain a vital result that
\begin{align*}
{\color{red}{f(x):=(\sin x)^x\ln x}}=\ln x+x\ln^2 x+\frac{1}{2}x^2\ln^3 x+\frac{1}{6}x^3\ln^4 x+o(x^3\ln^4 x).\tag{8}
\end{align*}

Morover, by $(1)(2)$, we have
\begin{align*}
x^{\sin x}&=\exp(\sin x\ln x)=1+\sin x\ln x+\frac{1}{2}\sin^2 x\ln^2 x+\frac{1}{6}\sin^3 x\ln^3 x+o(x^3\ln^3 x)\notag\\
&=1+x\ln x+\frac{1}{2} x^2\ln^2 x+\frac{1}{6}x^3\ln^3 x+o(x^3\ln^3 x).\tag{9}
\end{align*}
From $(5)(9)$, we oabtain another vital result that
\begin{align*}
&{\color{red}{g(x):=x^{\sin x}\ln\sin x}}\\
=&(1+x\ln x+\frac{1}{2} x^2\ln^2 x+\frac{1}{6}x^3\ln^3 x+o(x^3\ln^3 x))(\ln x-\frac{1}{6}x^2+o(x^3))\\
=&\ln x+x\ln^2 x+\frac{1}{2}x^2\ln^3 x+\frac{1}{6}x^3\ln^4 x-\frac{1}{6}x^2+o(x^3\ln^4 x).\tag{10}
\end{align*}

Now,notice that, by$(8)(10)$,
$$f(x)-g(x)=\frac{1}{6}x^2+o(x^3\ln^4 x)\to 0(x \to 0^+),$$
and, by $(10)$,
$$\frac{e^g(x)}{x}=e^{g(x)-\ln x}=e^{x\ln^2 x+o(x\ln^2 x)}=e^0=1.$$
It follows that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{x^{(\sin x)^x}-(\sin x)^{x^{\sin x}}}{x^3}&=\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{e^{f(x)}-e^{g(x)}}{x^3}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{e^{g(x)}(e^{f(x)-g(x)}-1)}{x^3}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{e^{g(x)}}{x}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{e^{f(x)-g(x)}-1}{x^2}\\
&=1 \cdot\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0+}\left(\frac{1}{6}+o(x\ln^4 x)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}.
\end{align*}