# Quotient rule for limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $\lim = \lim_{n \to +\infty}$.

When is $\lim \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \frac{\lim f(n)}{\lim g(n)}$ **always** ?

I know that $\lim g(n) \neq 0$ is one condition. Are there any other conditions?

Also, when is $\lim \left [g(n) - f(n) \right ] = \lim f(n) - \lim g(n)$ **always**? Like I know there is a problem when $\lim \left [g(n) - f(n) \right ]$ is finite, but the individual limits are not.

Can anyone summarize the conditions?

Comment: The limits of $f$ and of $g$ must actually exist.  The limit of one of them must be finite.  If both are infinite you have trouble.  If both are finite all is good (unless the denom is $0$).  If one is finite that the other infinite, I *think* things are okay *if* you are using the terminology that allow you to say "the limit equal infinity"  (Many text won't allow that.)

Comment: It is best to express it the form of a product. If $\lim f$ exists and is non zero then the limiting behavior of $fg$ is same as that of $g$. For quotient write $f/g=f(1/g)$

Comment: See this thread for more details. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971122/extended-limit-laws-for-step-by-step-evaluation-of-limits