# one limit divided into two limit factors, is it can one determine result directly but other don't?

Tags: limits

there is a question:

$$
\lim_{x->0}{\frac{x-arcsinx}{x^3(sinx+1)}} = \lim_{x->0}{\frac{1}{sinx+1}} · \lim_{x->0}{\frac{x-arcsinx}{x^3}}
$$

[1]you know there have four place `x`.
we know in limit calculation, if numerator `x` tend to `0`, the denominator `x` must tend to `0` too, so can get the correct result.

but in the given question, there divided into two lim's multiplication:$$\lim_{x->0}{\frac{1}{sinx+1}} · \lim_{x->0}{\frac{x-arcsinx}{x^3}}$$

there I named them as `lim_A`· `lim_B`.

in my opinion, the `lim_A` and `lim_B` comes from one entirety, if `lim_A`'s `x` tends to `0`, the `lim_B`'s `x` should tends to `0` too.

but however, in the question's solution there only let `lim_A`'s `x ->0` ignore the `lim_B`'s `x`,

$$\lim_{x->0}{\frac{1}{sinx+1}} · \lim_{x->0}{\frac{x-arcsinx}{x^3}} = \lim_{x->0}{\frac{x-arcsinx}{x^3}}$$

so, why ? is there any theorem state this step? (I don't understand because I think the `lim_A` and `lim_B` comes from one entity, if one `x->0`, the others(`lim_B`'s `x`) should `x->0` too.)

Comment: As far as I can understand,yoyr question is about taking limit of each factor separately. Here the first factor tends to $1 $ and we can safely replace this with $1$ and work on the limit of second factor.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh is there any way to prove?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/72031) as well as further proofs in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2971122/72031).

Comment: thanks, this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may also do it as $$L=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\sin^{-1}x}{x^3}$$
by letting $x=\sin t$ as
$$L=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin t- t}{\sin^3 t}= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1-t^3/3!+t^4/5!-...-t}{(t-t^3/3!+...)^3}=-\frac{1}{6}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note:  your English or typing needs help!  The word is opinion,not option.However there is no reason why both limits (not limitations) should $\to 0$.

For lim_B, get the first two terms in the power series for $arcsin(x)=x+\frac{x^3}{6}+...$  The answer is lim_B$=-\frac{1}{6}$