# Proving $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n $ Cantor's Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

In Cantor's Lemma, we prove $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n $ in the following way:

Let $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \, a_n = L $

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \, b_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \, (b_n - a_n) + a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \, b_n - a_n + \lim_{n \to \infty} \, a_n = 0 + L = L$

But why can't we just calculate it like this:

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \, b_n - a_n = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}\, b_n - \lim_{n \to \infty} \, a_n = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} \, b_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \, a_n$

The Lemma:
Let $ a_n, b_n $ be sequences such that $ \forall n, \, a_n \le a_{n + 1} \le b_{n + 1} \le b_n, \, \lim_{n \to \infty} (b_n - a_n) = 0$

$ a_n $ is bounded above by $ b_1 $ and $ \forall n, a_{n + 1} \ge a_n $. Therefore $ a_n $ is convergent.

$ b_n $ is bounded below by $ a_1 $ and $ \forall n, b_{n + 1} \le b_n $. Therefore, $ b_n $ is convergent.

Let $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L $

Therefore:

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} (b_n - a_n + a_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (b_n - a_n) + \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0 + L = L $

Comment: You've not said anything at all about $b_n$

Comment: The limit of the difference equals the difference of the limits only if both limits exist. The only reason I could think that your proof might not work is if the existence of the limit of $b_n$ is in question.

Comment: @SlipEternal In Cantor's Lemma, we prove that $ \inf\{b_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} $ is the limit of $ b_n $, so it does exist

Comment: It might be a good idea to state the lemma including the hyotheses for the sequences explicitely.

Comment: Your method is slightly unusual but not wrong. An extended version of limit laws allows us to handle this situation. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2971122/72031

Comment: You recieved an answer to your question. Is it what you needed? If so, consider accepting the answer. That's how the site works. If it is not what you needed, please explain what is still left unclear.

Answer (score 2):

> Let $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \, a_n = L $
>
> $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \, b_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \, (b_n - a_n) +
> a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \, b_n - a_n + \lim_{n \to \infty} \, a_n =
> 0 + L = L$
>
> But why can't we just calculate it like this:
>
> $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \, b_n - a_n = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to
> > \infty}\, b_n - \lim_{n \to \infty} \, a_n = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to
> > \infty} \, b_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \, a_n$

You certainly can do it either way. But since both ways are equally long, I don't see why the second would be inherenly *better* than the first.

In fact, I think the first way is better for at least two reasons:

(1) **Elegance**. The first way is a proof that consist entirely of equalities, that is it is of the form $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = ... = ... = ... = \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$, which is a very elegant form of a proof.

---

(2) **Lack of hidden assumptions**. Every equality in the first proof is completely justified by all the facts that are known beforehand:

1. $\lim_{n \to \infty} \, b_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \, (b_n - a_n) +
   a_n$ is true because $b_n = (b_n - a_n) + a_n$ is true.
2. $\lim_{n \to \infty} \, (b_n - a_n) +
   a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \, b_n - a_n + \lim_{n \to \infty} \, a_n$ is true because the limit of a sum is the sum of limits, **if the individual limits exist**, and ***we already know the two sublimits exist***.

In comparison, in your version of the proof, you assume that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \, b_n - a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\, b_n - \lim_{n \to \infty}$, but this is only true if the limit of $b_n$ exists, and this (while being true) is not explicitly stated. That makes the second proof less rigorous.